# Customizing header with simple macros

Tags: header-footer

For my first LaTeX book I need to access chapter, section
and subsection titles. Following an old posting (7/12) I wrote

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pagestyle{plain} % for now
\let\Chaptermark\chaptermark%
\def\chaptermark#1{\def\Chaptername{#1}\Chaptermark{#1}}%
\let\Sectionmark\sectionmark%
\def\sectionmark#1{\def\Sectionname{#1}\Sectionmark{#1}}%
\let\Subsectionmark\subsectionmark%
\def\subsectionmark#1{\def\Subsectionname{#1}\Subsectionmark{#1}}%
```

which was tested with

```
\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}\label{ch:first}
This is Chapter~\ref{ch:first} with title `\Chaptername''.
\section{First Section}\label{sec:first}
This is Section~\ref{sec:first} with title ``\Sectionname''.
\subsection{First Subsection}\label{subsec:first}
This is Subsection~\ref{subsec:first} with title ``\Subsectionname''.
\newpage
\chapter{Second Chapter}\label{ch:second}
This is Chapter~\ref{ch:second} with title ``\Chaptername''.
\section{First Section of Chapter 2}\label{sec:second}
This is Section~\ref{sec:second} with title ``\Sectionname''.
\subsection{First Subsection of Section 1 of Chapter 2}\label{subsec:second}
This is Subsection~\ref{subsec:second} with title ``\Subsectionname''.
\newpage
\chapter{Third Chapter}\label{ch:third}
This is Chapter~\ref{ch:third} with title ``\Chaptername''.
\section{First Section of Chapter 3}\label{sec:third}
This is Section~\ref{sec:third} with title ``\Sectionname''.
\subsection{First Subsection of Section 1 of Chapter 3}\label{subsec:third}
This is Subsection~\ref{subsec:third} with title ``\Subsectionname''.
\end{document}
```

Works fine, no extra packages needed.  My target page header format is

```
 even pages:  chapter#:  current chapter title
 odd pages:   \S chapter#.section#:  current section title
```

with page # at footer center. Can that be done with the `\markleft`
plus `\markright` duo and the above `\Chaptername`, etc, or should
those macros be modified using `\def`?

Comment: please put your code in box, it's not readable right now.

Comment: Where do you want the header at? left, center or right? Do they should switch location when `twoside` option used. Your requirement isn't clear. What is `\S` mean?

Comment: @Tom Presumably `\S` is what it normally is in LaTeX: the symbol §

Comment: @frabjous Thank you!

Comment: There is no `\markleft` in LaTeX. There is `\markboth` and `\markright`, which should be used inside the `\chaptermark` and `\sectionmark` commands. They can then be picked up with `\leftmark` and `\rightmark` in the headers. The easiest way is to use the package `fancyhdr` to define the headers and footers.